# How do I make Home and End work in PuTTY SSH with fish shell?

Tags: bash, keyboard, ssh, putty, fish

Years ago, an Ubuntu update broke this and I've never found a solution.

- I have [fish](http://fishshell.com/) as my default shell.
- Ubuntu 12.10
- Locally (Gnome Terminal), Home and End keys work fine in both fish and bash.
- When I log in by SSH using PuTTY, then run `bash`, Home and End work fine inside of bash.
- However, when I log in by SSH using PuTTY, in the default fish shell, pressing Home key produces `[1~` (sometimes erasing the line, sometimes not).  When I press End, it produces `[4~`.
- If I use the default fish shell in Bitvise SSH client, Home and End work correctly.

How do I get Home and End to work correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
bind \e\[1~ beginning-of-line
bind \e\[3~ delete-char
bind \e\[4~ end-of-line
```

You can preserve this setting by append this option at `fish_default_key_bindings`:

```
/usr/share/fish/functions/fish_default_key_bindings.fish
```

*Caution!* If you have a typing error with the setting file, some keys doesn't work :)

See also [Home/End keys broken in screen when term is set to xterm](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/180)